# Z3 nth-function missing in Java API?

Tags: java, api, z3, smt

referring to this post [How do you extract an element as the base type from a Seq type in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696982/how-do-you-extract-an-element-as-the-base-type-from-a-seq-type-in-z3) 
there is support for 'nth' operation for sequences. The given code of the post does run on my local z3 4.8.8 . But when trying to 'replay' the example via the Java API it seems 'nth' is missing?! Does it have another name?

Help appreciated....

Comment: Did you try `mkSeqNth`. I believe that's what it is called in the Java API.

Comment: I am using 4.8.8 and it is simply not there! Which version are you talking about?

Comment: You can find it in ,Net-APi, But not in the Java-API (https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/)